# consequence-free environment meaning?

Tags: meaning

**consequence-free environment meaning?**

Critics have specifically pointed out that Sarahah and other similar apps offer a consequence-free environment where users can send anonymous messages that could be perfectly innocuous, or incredibly hurtful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send a hurtful message that can be traced back to you, then there might be consequences, which is a mild way of saying that you could be in big trouble.

The app named Sarahah, apparently, removes that risk because it permits messages to be sent that cannot be traced back to the sender. So the sender is no longer going to get into trouble if he or she sends hurtful messages. Hence, the sender is "free" of "consequences": in short in a "consequence-free environment".

Answer (score 1):

The pattern  `{noun}-free` means "having no {noun}".  You can put almost any noun in the {noun} position to generate a new adjectival word.

Fragrance-free = having no fragrance or perfume

Duty-free = without any duty (that is, a tax levied on items produced in another country)

Salt-free = having no salt, without any salt

Risk-free = having no risk, without any risk

Worry-free =  without any worry

Care-free = without any care (that is, no anxieties or troubles) [This combination is used so often that it has become a single word, *carefree*]

Consequence-free = having no consequence

**Consequences** are the (usually distressful) results of some action or inaction.

If you rob a bank and get caught, you can go to jail.  If you never go to class and miss all of the exams, you will fail the course.  If you do not water the plant on your windowsill, it may wither and die.  Those are the *consequences* of your actions and inactions.